# A runnable jar contains all packages within a project

Tags: eclipse, jar

I created a runnable jar through export, but the jar file size was so large that all packages were included in the project. However, the main class did not import any classes in the project. How do I fix it?
(main class: torunc.ToRunCMain) [image]

[image]

Comment: If your main class has no use for any other classes in the same project, perhaps this calls for a second project?